# what is the possibility of migrating Hibernate from version 3.1 to 5.1

Tags: java, hibernate, migration

My Hibernate is woefully out of date so Ineed to explore what is involved in migrating version 3.1 to version 5.1 which is one version that doesn't require Java 8 I guess.

I  read through the full set of migration guides: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/wiki/Migration-Guides this one explains the migration from x.y to x.z.But I was unable to configure my doubts.

My concerns are:
 Does it still support hbm files in 5.1 or do we need to use annotations only?
 what are the possible conflicts? 
 Any Data type issues in general?

Comment: hbm files are still supported, however there are likely to be some incompatibilities. Since no such changes are listed, you will have to find-out what those incompatibilities are by doing the migration.

Comment: Thank you, it was really helpful, much appreciated.